# adding timer countdown using keith-wood

Tags: jquery

```
i have followed all the steps as in
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

i have downloaded the following files
```

jquery .plugin.js ,jquery.countdown.js 
    and
    jquery.countdown.css ..from keith-wood website.

```
i am having errors in these files i dont understand it.
error is like this after checking from inspect element.
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  jquery.plugin.js:344

and same for jquery.countdown.js
   can any one help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow step 1 and include the jQuery library in your HTML too

If you already did, then make sure that the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is above the lines that you included in step 2.

Place the code from steps 1 and 2 in your HTML file in this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```